# JList: displaying other thing than stored

Tags: java, linked-list, jlist

I have a JList Component and I would like to store paths of the images but to display name of image, not the path. I have a code of pressing Opening File Button like that:

```
 public void openButtonActionPerformed() {       

    int returnVal = fc.showDialog(null, "Open");

     if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
           file = fc.getSelectedFile();
     }
    jList1.setCellRenderer(new JavaRenderer());
}
```

And:

```
class JavaRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

public JavaRenderer(){
    //setOpaque(true);
}
 public File file;  

 public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                            Object value,
                                            int index,
                                            boolean isSelected,
                                            boolean hasFocus) {

if (value instanceof File) {
  File file = (file) value;

     return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, file.getName(), index, isSelected, hasFocus);
}else {
     return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, hasFocus);
}
}
}
```

But it still doesn't work. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jList.setCellRenderer()` where you pass `new DefaultListCellRenderer()` with overrided method

`getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
      boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)`

`value` - is an object that you insert to JList, so you can store it but show another label:

```
if (value instanceof File) {
   File file = (File) value;
   return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, file.getName(), index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
} else {
   return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
}
```

Comment: I edited my post due to your clues. It doesn't work and I know that the mistake is stupid but i can't find it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You need to call `jList1.setCellRenderer(new JavaRenderer());` only once, where you initialize your jList. Then you must add File to jList using listModel. See [adding items to jList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable)

Comment: Thanks, actually problem was in `File file = (file) value;` because I thoughtlessly copied it and there should File instead of file. Thanks for your help and patience for beginner : )

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a [ListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) of your own, where you store `List<File>` internally and return fileName from `getElementAt(int index)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way your content renders in the JList by creating your own ListCellRenderer. (Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the supplied answers here is another way. You can wrap the File object in your own File class. Then overload the toString() method to return the filename.

```
class CustomFile extends File{
    public CustomFile(File f){super(f.getAbsolutePath());}
    public String toString(){return getName();}
}
```